# Create a TH2 which contains the standard deviation of a variable in a given bin

Tags: c++, histogram, mean, standard-deviation, root-framework

I have an XY map of event positions in a particle detector, and those events have dozens of variables which characterize them. Take energy, for instance: I can find the average energy of an event in a small region of the detector by making three TH2F's in ROOT:

```
TH2F* h_xy  = new TH2F("h_xy","h_xy",100,-10,10,100,-10,10);
TH2F* h_xyw = new TH2F("h_xyw","h_xyw",100,-10,10,100,-10,10);
TH2F* h_avg = new TH2F("h_avg","h_avg",100,-10,10,100,-10,10);
```

I fill `h_xy` with all of my events, distributed over xy. Each entry in the histogram is weighted to 1. Then, I fill `h_xyw` with all of my events, weighted by the energy. Dividing `h_xyw` by `h_xy` gives the average energy per bin, which I put into `h_avg`. I do all of this on the ROOT command line, so it's really easy to just:

```
tree->Draw("energy>>h_xy","","colz")
```

And then pull the information right out of the histograms. **Next**, I'd like to be able to plot the **standard deviation** of the weights in each bin, in addition to the average. I know I can do this by writing a compiled script, but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this command-line that I just haven't thought of.

Comment: How did you do the division of two Hisograms? You need to do a loop to do the division or you have command line to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: @HuanianZhang (this is probably way too late to be useful for you), but TH2 inherits all methods from TH1 and [TH1 has a Divide() method](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTH1.html#a4ef2329285beb6091515b836e160bd9f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your existing commands, you can fill another histogram `h_xyww` with the energy squared as weigths. Then you divide `h_xyww` by `h_xy` (average squared energy), multiply the histogram with the average energies by itself (square of average energy), and then subtract the two from each other.

```
std_dev^2 = <E^2> - <E>^2
```

Comment: Ah, that's so simple! I was completely ignoring that definition of the standard deviation -- focusing on the event-by-event sum. This is exactly what I needed, thanks!